# передать значение из input в переменную без перезагрузки

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

Привет, в woocommerce встроенная функция передает переменную $quantity методом post, но как сделать свое поле input, чтобы в этот код передавалось значение без перезагрузки страницы?

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product );
```

код который использует woocommerce для input

```
woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 1, $product ),
                'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $product->get_stock_quantity(), $product ),
                'input_value' => ( isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] ) : 1 )
            ) );
```

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду AJAX?

Comment: Переформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос. Не совсем ясно, о чем вы говорите. Если вы имеете ввиду AJAX - это технология в основном клиентская и касается javascript и немного html, а вы демонстрируете только php.

Comment: возможно) не знаю с помощью чего мне сделать форму ввода числа, чтобы это значение сразу записывалось в переменную и можно было передать её в php код без обновления страницы. Форма типа такая <input name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол-во" class="input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" type="number">. Как я понимаю мне нужен javascript который передаст значение в переменную, но нужно без перезагрузки страницы

Comment: да, вам нужно работать с JS. а точнее - AJAX, как уже было замечено. И мне кажется, вы не до конца понимаете различия клиент-сервер. Вам нужно передать переменную не в php-код, а на сервер. php выполняется на сервере, javascript и все input и весь html - это на клиенте.

Answer (score 1):

проблему решил) вот скриптик)

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $( document ).on( 'change', '.quantity .qty', function() {
        $( this ).parent( '.quantity' ).next( '.add_to_cart_button' ).attr( 'data-quantity', $( this ).val() );
    });
});
```